# Testing AJAX with Jasmine - correct values but with error

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am trying to test a function that makes an AJAX request to an API. The value that the function sends to the API and the API's response are as expected. However, Jasmine keeps giving me `Error: Expected Function to be "*insert random string*".` How can I run this test properly and without errors via browser standalone version of Jasmine?

This is the function I am trying to test:

```
function handleInput(data) {

    var dataToSend = data;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open("POST", "http://test.app/controllers/handleinput.php", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.onload = function () {
            console.log(this.responseText);
           return this.responseText;
        };
        xhr.send("input=" + dataToSend);
}
```

This is the specs script:

```
describe('ajax request', function () {

  var randomString = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);

  beforeEach(function (done) {
        handleInput(randomString)
        done();
    });

  it('receives the same string that it sends', function (done) {
    expect(handleInput).toBe(randomString);
    done();
  });
});
```

All I am trying to do is to verify that the function `handleInput` sends a random string to the server and receives the same string as the response.

Comment: `expect(handleInput).toBe(randomString)` - `handleInput` is a *function*, not a value.  You're trying to compare it to a value.  What should this test actually be validating?  `handleInput()` doesn't return anything.  You'd need to somehow validate that the console was logged to, since that's all it does.  (You could provide mocks to the function for `xhr` and `console` and test the interactions with those mocks.  That'll be a pretty significant change to your code.)

Comment: @David `handleInput` is supposed to return the value of the `responseText` property when `xhr.onload` is ready. All I am trying to do is to make sure that the value the function sends to the server is the same value that is returned by the server. How could I do that?

Comment: In that case you're going about it incorrectly.  The linked duplicate explains the problem you're facing, where you're trying to synchronuosly return a response from an asynchronous operation.

Comment: @David but isn't that what the beforeEach method is for and why done() is invoked?